# wxPython "Things are going to break" error

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

Ok so I'm working with wxPython with a friend of mine, now it just so happened that he implemented a new picture into the script and its working just fine for him. But if he sends the project to me I get the error:
"wx._core.wxAssertionError: C++ assertion "strcmp(setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL), "C") == 0" failed at ....\src\common\intl.cpp(1579) in wxLocale::GetInfo(): You probably called setlocale() directly instead of using wxLocale and now there is a mismatch between C/C++ and Windows locale.
Things are going to break, please only change locale by creating wxLocale objects to avoid this!"
The code in the line that breaks is the following:`png2 = wx.Image("BlackBorder.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()` this lies inside the `__init__(self)` method for wxPython

It doesnt really tell me what is wrong I feel like so I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, there are some versions of the PNG library that call setlocale in some situations. Try explicitly creating and holding a `wx.Locale` object at the start of your application and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem after updating my application from Python27 to Python3.
4 PCs worked fine but one user with French as their windows language had this error.

I solved my problem by "initialising" the wx.Locale() at the beginning of my application:

```
class Application(wx.Frame):
def __init__(self, parent, title):
    self.locale = wx.Locale()
    self.locale.Init(wx.LANGUAGE_ENGLISH)
```

Comment: I have found a problem with this solution if you want to use datetime.strptime().
There seems to be a bug in the python Locale() which causes the following error:
    return _parse_localename(localename)
       raise ValueError(unknown locale: en-GB)

See bug report here: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/87281

It seems that between Python3 & wx 4.1.1 the locale handling is a tricky to manage.
I think Im going to go back to Python2.7 where everything just seemed to work :)

Comment: The solution seems to mention Python 3.8 introduced this problem, however, I am using Python 3.7.9.
Perhaps the same change from 3.8 has been backported into one of the bugfixes of 3.7

Comment: Here is the discussion from DiscussPython: https://discuss.wxpython.org/t/wxpython4-1-1-python3-8-locale-wxassertionerror/35168

Comment: I landed here searching for the same failed assertion text. My locale ("regional format") was "English (German)" and I could at least mitigate by switching to "English (United States)".

Comment: If I remember correctly, this wx.locale issue is corrected in the latest version of wx with the same change that is suggested by Robin. It is slightly different than the solution I posted originally & I changed my applicants to use Robins solutions. I will post my code tomorrow when I'm on the work laptop